# URL rewriting apache2

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, regex

How would I be able to rewrite

`anyhost.com/argument1/parameter2/some-text/`

as

`anyhost.com/index.php?path=argument1/parameter2/some-text/`

or

`anyhost.com/index.php?page=argument1&subpage=parameter2&subsubpage=some-text`

or anything like that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, for the purposes of SEO, etc., I think you may be looking at this backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]

# Second example
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&subsubpage=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is to auto-append any query string from the original URL to the query string sent to index.php; you can remove it if you don't need that functionality.

Comment: Ay ay, I the first rule is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule (.*)?/ index.php?path=$1
```

This is for the first version.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)?/ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&subsubpage=$3
```

This is for the second one. You can always test your rewrites using [this tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).